# How to not deselect react-select when clicking dev tools to style it

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, react-select

My typical workflow when choosing styles for a component is to use the dev-tools in the browser to play around with the styles until I'm happy with the look, and then copy the chosen styles permanently back to the code.

But if I want to see the dropdown in react-select, I need to click it. When I click back to the dev-tool, the dropdown disappears as the component is de-selected.

Is there a way to keep the dropdown open as I style it?

Here's a sandbox if you want to try: https://codesandbox.io/s/4rlmrp38j7

Answer (score 1):

I just found the prop `menuIsOpen` which will force the dropdown to stay open.

However, if there is a way using the dev-tools or another method I'd be interested in that too and will happily mark that as more robust and correct than this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You would recommend you to use some extension to inspect the code `React`:

- for [chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi)
- for [firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/react-devtools/)

Then in `react-select` v1 you can set `isOpen` and in v2 `menuIsOpen` to `true` without changing you code. 
I will also suggest to take a look at [this page](https://react-select.com/styles) and directly in the source code on the [repo github](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/src/styles.js) to have an idea of the default style.